# Bootstrap 3 not styling navbar items properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I don't really know why bootstrap isnt styling the navbar items correctly, this is my markup

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dokimi-navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Dokimi</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="dokimi-navbar">   
            <ul class="nav nvabar-nav">
                <li ><a href="dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="classes">Classes</a></li>
                <li ><a href="groups">Groups</a></li>
                <li ><a href="students">Students</a></li>
                <li ><a href="discussions">Discussions</a></li>
                <li ><a href="settings">Settings</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><img style="display:inline;border-radius:2px;" alt="you" src=""> Hey, you <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="profile.php">My Profile</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="logout.php">Log out</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

But this is how it is rendered in my browser: [image: blocks].  The W3C validator shows my markup as valid, so I don't think I missed a closing tag.  I've spend a few hours on this and I think I just need a second set of eyes to look it over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in the class name, change:

```
<ul class="nav nvabar-nav">
    <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

To:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```